# How to keep only the last 20 elements of a slice

Tags: go, slice

Say I have a slice and the length is greater than 20:

```
if len(requestHistory) > 20 {
  requestHistory = requestHistory[:20]  // bogus code
}
```

what I want to do is keep only the last 20 elements and discard any elements in front, how can I do that safely?

Comment: What does "safely" mean? There's nothing unsafe about this, nor is there anything unsafe about slicing the last 20 elements.

Comment: safely would mean doing it without the `if` block, and still keeping it safe. the if block protects the wreck, but without the if block it might be unsafe my G, ya seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply slice the last 20 elements:

```
if len(requestHistory)>20 {
   requestHistory=requestHistory[len(requestHistory)-20:]
}
```